# Does symsum in Matlab do more than it should?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-computation

I have the following loop

```
syms k m
summ = symsum(k^2,k,1,m)
for j=1:100
  summ = subs(symsum((m-j)^2*summ,m,j+1,k),k,m);
end
```

and it takes about 600s to calculate it on R2014a, W7, 64b. An equivalent calculation in Mathematica takes 60s. The result is identical but there is a difference. One of the properties of all sums (in this case all one hundred of them) is that it can be factorized in a semi-nice way. Mathematica does not factorize it by default because it is not told to do so. But symsum does it by checking the sums and that, I think, is the source of a slowdown.

Would you agree? If yes, is there a way to tell symsum to not simplify the output? If no, is there a way so speed it up? I really would like to do it in Matlab than in Mathematica.

Comment: My guess is that the slowdown is due to reallocating large amounts of memory on each iteration of your `for` loop. Not much (if any) of Matlab's Symbolic Math toolbox gets runtime compiled/optimized. Mathematica being a computer algebra system first and foremost may be different. It looks like you may have [product of a sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_Pi_notation) in your code. You may be able to use [`symprod`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symprod.html). I'm not going to try to figure out what your actual equation is from the code.

Comment: I forced Mathematica to factor the sum at each step and it is still faster - but only twice as much. So this must be due to the optimization you mentioned. But I really think the main culprit for the slowdown is symsum being too proactive...